# Translate .bat coomands to .vbs

Tags: windows, boot, batch-file, vbscript

I need to run this code but without the "black CMD window". Googeing I understood that VBS scripts are "invisible" on startup, so can someone please translate this code for .vbs file?

```
@echo off
set delay=1

ping localhost -n %delay%
net use Z: "\\GMEDIASTATION\music"
net use Y: "\\GMEDIASTATION\Public"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\AlbumPlayer\AlbumPlayer.exe"
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I guessed that from the code its already clear what I'm trying to achieve.

I want to delay the mounting the net drives than invoke .exe application and I want this to be hidden from the user. 

Putting startup.bat in the Startup folder runs it but with the command prompt window in the back. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Let me rephrase it then "We are not  a code translation service" does that help you understand?

Comment: Ok, I got that from your first post. Is my explanation more clearer now?

Comment: Your explanation might be more clear now but you're still asking for code translation, a service not offered by superuser. If you google `vbs ping`, `vbs net use` and `vbs run exe` you'll find all info needed.

Comment: Do you specifically not want a cmd window at all, or do you just not want to see it in the foreground? You can create a shortcut to your batch file and have it start minimized.

Comment: You could also write a very simple VBS script, that runs the batch file hidden.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking SuperUser to complete an action or service instead of find out the answer to a question.

Answer (score 0):

Run the script from task scheduler with another user account or with the System account. That way nothing will be showed for the user.